# Как правильно преобразовать список в словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу создать из списка словарь:

```
p_01_list = [['f1', 'v1'], ['f2', 'v2'], ['f3', 'v3']]
p_01_dict = dict(p_01_list)
```

Получаю

```
{'f1': 'v1', 'f2': 'v2', 'f3': 'v3'}
```

В принципе, на выходе получаю, то, что и хотел.
Но PyCharm ругается на конструкцию `dict(p_01_list)`:

> `"Unexpected type(s): (List[List[str]]). Possible types: (Mapping), Iterable[Tuple[Any, Any]])"`

Подскажите, как сделать правильно, чтобы не было ошибок?
 Какая конструкция здесь будет верной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p_01_dict = dict(map(tuple, p_01_list))
```